# Is there a way to 'get' all connected entities and their attributes connected to a specific instance of an entity?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I want to display all the data points for a specific instance of an entity.

I understand how to write the query in a specific form but I want it to be more general and be more concise.

This is what I currently have:

```
match 
$t isa technology, has version "v9.5";
$as isa app-server, has database-server $ds, has dot-net-network $dnn, has XXXXXX $x1, has XXXXXX $x2;
$ds isa database-server, has XXXXXX $x3, has XXXXXX $x4;
$r1(container: $t, containee: $as);
$r2(container: $t, containee: $ds);
get; offset 0; limit 30;
```

There are several more entities connecting to my `container`.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "all the data points for a specific instance of an entity". The query you write is as specific as the question you want to get the answer to. What would be the more generic question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in Graql we can make ambiguous queries by providing less constraints in the query, or changing a constraint to a more relaxed one.

In your case, I believe you want to ask a question specifically about an entity instance, described by this pattern: `$t isa technology, has version "v9.5";`. You want to find the entities it is connected to via a relation. You then wish to find all of the attributes of those connected entities, but without specifying all of the types of attribute those entities could own according to the schema.

The most generic way to get the connected concepts is:

```
match 
$t isa technology, has version "v9.5";
$r($t, $e);
get $e;
```

If you want connected *entities* only:

```
match 
$t isa technology, has version "v9.5";
$r($t, $e);
$e isa entity;
get $e;
```

This is because all of your user-defined entities inherit from `entity`. You can do the same for `relation` and `attribute`, or `thing` which is the super type of all three.

**The full answer** to get all of the *attributes* of a concept, is to use the same principal, giving the base type `attribute`:

```
match 
$t isa technology, has version "v9.5";
$r($t, $e);
$e isa entity, has attribute $a;
get $e, $a;
```

**Bonus**
You can then find attributes common to two patterns, in this case two `technology` instances:

```
match
$t1 isa technology, has version "v9.5";
$e1 isa entity, has attribute $a;
$r1($t1, $e1);
$t2 isa technology, has version "v9.6";
$e2 isa entity, has attribute $e;
$r2($t2, $x2);
get $a;
```